# How to know if a method has been defined in an interface

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Given the following code:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun foo() {
        // body
    }

    fun bar() {
        // body
    }
}

class MyInterfaceImpl: MyInterface {
    override fun bar() {
        // body
    }
}
```

I need to know at runtime that `bar()` has been overridden and `foo()` hasn't. How to do this using reflection?

Note: `java.lang.reflect.Method#getDeclaringClass()` always returns `MyInterfaceImpl::class.java` and `java.lang.reflect.Method#isDefault()` always returns `false`. I did not find the solution in `KClass`.

Comment: With your current code, it would not compile if both methods were not overridden from the interface. What exactly are you looking for? Is MyInterfaceImpl intended to abstract? What happens if the interface method is overridden in an intermediate parent class of MyInterfaceImpl?

Comment: `MyInterface` defines a body for both methods, so the snippet compile. `MyInterfaceImpl` is not abstract. And if the interface method is overridden in an intermediate parent class, I think I'd like to know which class implements the method.

Comment: Ah right, forgot default methods in Kotlin don't require that to be explicitly stated.

Comment: I'm interested if someone else has a solution. Spent some time looking into it but I'm not convinced that it's actually possible. Also curious what your actual use case is for this, as there may be another approach?

Comment: I'll probably add a suggestion on github in a few days (if no solution). About my use case: the real interface defines 6 methods, all optional. Depending on 2 inputs, we use one implementation and one method (or another). If the implementation does not override the method, an exception is thrown (defined in the interface bodies). At runtime we display the methods overridden so the client can check if the method is available or not. I'll check for a pattern matching my use case (I'm pretty sure there is one), but I guess it would make my code a lot more complicated. Thanks for your time btw.

Comment: Note: this interface may have about 25-30 implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare `MyInterfaceImpl::class.declaredFunctions` and `MyInterface::class.declaredFunctions`.

This property lists all functions declared in this class.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, where are two ways to achieve that dubious goal.

I'll demonstrate easy one, and discuss idea behind the harder one.

Easy one is based on simply calling toString() on the method:

```
val functions = MyInterfaceImpl::class.functions

val bar = (functions.toList()[0]) 
val foo = (functions.toList()[2]) 

println(bar.toString()) // fun MyInterfaceImpl.bar(): kotlin.Unit
println(foo.toString()) // fun MyInterface.foo(): kotlin.Unit
```

As you can see, you can figure if the method was overridden or not by parsing the string.

Harder solution would be to dig into `KFunctionImpl`, which has `delegate` member, which has `dispatchReceiverParameter`

That's a lot of nasty reflection, which is even more nasty, because most of those classes are internal and lazily initialized.

Comment: Which Kotlin version did you use? With 1.3.10 I got this result: `fun MyInterfaceImpl.bar(): kotlin.Unit` `fun MyInterfaceImpl.foo(): kotlin.Unit`. I'll dig into your suggestion.

Comment: I'm on 1.3.10 too. I wish I could share it on TryKotlin, but it blocks reflection for obvious reasons.

Comment: I found an easy solution. Thanks for putting me on the way.